# backendless 3 или 4

Tags: java, android, база-данных

С какой версии лучше начать использование сервиса backendless?

Если с 4, то, насколько я понимаю, все будет хоститься у меня на ПК, верно?

Если с 3, то все в облаке.

Или стоит начать с 3 версии, а когда 4 выйдет из беты, мигрировать на неё? И сложно ли будет это сделать? И ещё вопрос- поддерживает ли Backendless 4 REST Api?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего надо использовать последнюю версию, так как старая будет иметь ограниченное время поддержки. Чем дольше оставаться на старой версии - тем тяжелее будет мигрировать, так как в новых версиях меняется API. Rest API в 4-й есть.